# How to access eclipse's editor templates via plugin code?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I am developing a plugin which gives me access to the editor templates inside eclipse.

The ones I'd like access to are those access by going to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Templates

I have already tried the solutions given on these links:

[Eclipse: Accessing a editor template from plugin code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/442138/eclipse-accessing-a-editor-template-from-plugin-code)

[Contributing a template to Eclipse via a Plugin to the Java Editor, but should vary based on the context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29443263/contributing-a-template-to-eclipse-via-a-plugin-to-the-java-editor-but-should-v)

The solutions given in the links above give access to the templates which one accesses by going to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Code Templates, which I **don't** want.

[Add Java code template programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005003/add-java-code-template-programmatically)

Also, I looked at the source of [JavaTemplatePreferencePage.java](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/d505e940db2612e7f52f0aed901ab73cfe8f2438/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/preferences/JavaTemplatePreferencePage.java) in order to find some code that I could use or probably get a hint from, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29461347/2670892) to your first link looks correct to me. It is using code from the internal class `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.JavaPlugin`

Comment: @greg-449 I tried that. It doesn't work. Just to confirm whether I'm accessing the right templates, when I tried printing their names, this is what I got: `gettercomment
settercomment
constructorcomment
filecomment
typecomment
fieldcomment
methodcomment
overridecomment
delegatecomment
newtype
classbody
interfacebody
enumbody
annotationbody
catchblock
methodbody
constructorbody
getterbody
setterbody`